# usb to rs232 serial communication

Tags: usb, rs232, configuration, serial-bus

[image]

I have to configure my rs232 to device(transmitter) using usb to serial communication. I have tried with usb to rs232 cable and connect the transmitter 6 pins to the db9 connector but it did not work. any suggestions!

Comment: What is the device?

Comment: We need more details of the USB-RS232 converter, and a more detailed diagram/table of how you connected your device.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. It also does look like an end-user question. What device, what usb-rs232, what software?

Comment: This is ABB Aqua master flowmeter transmitter,i used unitek usb to rs232 converter,used hyper terminal to configure the transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

If it's RS232 -12V to 12V levels, did you use an actual USB to RS232 adapter?

If it's a TTL serial UART of 5V or 3.3V or other voltage, did you use a USB to TTL serial adapter?

Did you connect the Device TX to the Adapter RX, and Device RX to Adapter TX?

If you made sure of that, then it should work, short of a bad/faulty adapter or driver issues.

Comment: I used unitek usb to rs232 converter.i connected the transmitter rxd,txd & ground to rs232 converter txd,rxd & ground and used hyper terminal to configure the transmitter. In manual they are saying press Tab key 3 times to activate the programming mode, i did but there is no response in the hyper terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

transmitter
(7pin MIL connector)      rs232 to usb converter(DB9)
RXD ---------------------- TXD
TXD----------------------- RXD
RTS----------------------- CTS
CTS------------------------RTS
Ground---------------------Ground
RI-------------------------RI
I connected these pins and used hyper terminal for the configuration.